# Can we bid in the next auction even though our starting lease is 2 leases away?

Tags: polkadot, kusama

The current lease is 20 on Kusama.

We have elected to go for leases 22-29.

The upcoming auction is #33

This next auction is bidding for leases 21-28. (We have locked in 22-29).

Please check the below statements if they’re correct:

0. Are we able to bid in the next auction?
1. Therefore we can only bid for 22-28, correct.
2. If so how much more do we need to bid in total to beat a competitor? Given that we are missing the 21st lease. Or is it the other way round and we don’t need as much total bid?
3. how do we bid for the missing 29th lease period?
4. can a chain bid in auction without being in a crowdloan? If so are they bidding as an individual?

Answer (score 1):

0. no
1. yes
2. hard to say depends on your competitor,the auction will just pickup winner(s) for it's best earning
3. you can create another crowdloan for the missing period or just bid individually as mentioned
4. same as 3